# If there a faster/better optimized way to check if value's in range made of another value?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

my friend and I were wondering today if we can optimize a part of code. I couldn't find anything similiar, I mean there are ways of doing it but it's kinda different what we have and it's never about optimization and range also changes.
So the current code is:

```
if (((this.TempMingraph + skok) < Convert.ToInt32(datalegend[0])) ||
   ((this.TempMingraph - skok) > Convert.ToInt32(datalegend[0])))
       this.TempMingraph = Convert.ToInt32(datalegend[0]);

if (((this.TempMaxgraph + skok) < Convert.ToInt32(datalegend[1])) ||
   ((this.TempMaxgraph - skok) > Convert.ToInt32(datalegend[1])))
       this.TempMaxgraph = Convert.ToInt32(datalegend[1]);

if (this.ScaleVoltageFlag)
{
    ActualThread_ChartAxesScaleMinMax(chart, TempMingraph - skok, TempMaxgraph + skok);
```

Explanation:
we have two values from "outside", we can only convert them to INT32 since we need to work on values instead of strings, those values are datalegend[0] and datalegend[1]. Values are integers always and in range of few thousands and never equals to 0.

Our helper values are: TempMingraph and TempMaxgraph. WE need to check exactly the same things on both of them but using different values: for TempMingraph we have to use outside value of datalegend[0] and for TempMaxgraph we have to use outside value of datalegend[1].

So each "Temp" value which are always integers, are a "base" for a range to check. Let's take TempMingraph so the range to check is from TempMingraph - skok (skok equals int = 10) to TempMingraph + skok. We need to check if datalegend[0] is within that range. If not, TempMingraph = datalegend[0], that's easy. And then exactly the same for TempMaxgraph but comparing to datalegend[1]. Constant skok remains the same. Last if is not important, just sets new values. Is that the best/fastest way to do that? If not, how would you solve it?

Comment: You should make use of some additional variables (for instance a variable to hold the value of `Convert.ToInt32(datalegend[0])`) to simplify your code. At the moment, it's painful to read because of all the duplication.

Comment: Clarity aside, doing `Convert.ToInt()` just once on a given var is the first thing I would optimize

Comment: You said "We need to check if datalegend[0] is within that range" but your if statements use || instead of &&. I believe you want to use &&.

Comment: No, we need || here, if we chose &&, that'd be always false and the value would never change to another. Question is not about how to make it work, it works just fine. We're thinking only about making it faster/better optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would probably do it - Since both conditions are repeating, I would move them to a method. Also, they are much simpler once you deal with only int values and remove all the unnecessary brackets:

```
this.TempMingraph = CalculateGraphValue(this.TempMingraph, skok, Convert.ToInt32(datalegend[0]));
this.TempMaxgraph = CalculateGraphValue(this.TempMingraph, skok, Convert.ToInt32(datalegend[1]));


private int CalculateGraphValue(int graph, int skok, int datalegend)
{
    return (graph + skok < datalegend || graph - skok > datalegend) ? datalegend : graph;
}
```

The method simply returns the value of either `datalegend` or `graph`, depending on the values of `graph`, `skok` and `datalegend`.